# Quantum optimization and correlation function

Tags: optimization, ising-model

If one imagines the nodes of the classical weighted graph as atoms, and paths between them as bonding strength, then to find the shortest path in the weighted graph, can one also look at the minima/maxima of the correlation function of the spin of the atoms? Correlation function of the spins along $z$-axis might look like:

$$G_z(i_1, \cdots i_n) = \langle T\bigr\{\sigma_{i_1, z}(t_1)\sigma_{i_2, z}(t_2),\cdots,\sigma_{i_n, z}(t_n)\bigr\}\rangle\tag{1}$$

Where $\sigma_{i_k, z}(t_k)$ denotes spin-$z$ component at the site $i_k$ and instant $t_k$ on the lattice, and where $T$ is time-ordering operator. The lower bonding strength between atoms is, the lower the correlation between their spins should be. In which case I thought optimal classical path can be associated with the sites of the lattice that exhibit the weakest/strongest correlation, yet I am not really sure whether there's a theoretical flaw in this idea (highly likely).